# when would python stuck at time.sleep function?

Tags: python, selenium, thread-sleep

Currently, I'm using `selenium` in `python` to do something which needs a never-end-up loop to monitor what I want, here's the code snippet:

```
records = set()
fileHandle = open('d:/seizeFloorRec.txt', 'a')
fileHandle.write('\ncur time: '+time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.localtime(time.time()))+'\n')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
while(True):
    try:
        print "time: ", time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.localtime(time.time()))
        subUrls = aMethod(driver) # a irrelevant function which returns a list
        time.sleep(2)
        for i in range(0, len(subUrls)): 
            print "cur_idx=["+str(i)+"], max_cnt=["+str(len(subUrls))+"]"
            try:
                rtn = monitorFloorKeyword(subUrls[i])
                time.sleep(1.5)
                if(rtn[0] == True):
                    if(rtn[1] not in records):
                        print "hit!"
                        records.add(rtn[1])
                        fileHandle.write(rtn[1]+'\t'+rtn[2].encode('utf-8')+'\n')
                        fileHandle.flush()
                    else:
                        print "hit but not write."
            except Exception as e:
                print "exception when get page: ", subUrls[i]
                print e.__doc__
                continue

        print "sleep 5*60 sec..."
        time.sleep(300)  # PROBLEM LIES HERE!!!
        print "sleep completes."

    except Exception as e:
        print 'exception!'
        print e.__doc__
        time.sleep(20)
```

it always stucks **unpredictably** at `time.sleep(300)`, with the output "sleep 5*60 sec..." yet without "sleep completes.".

Could anyone just give me some probable cause to this phenomenon? Thanks a lot!

**UPDATED**

I've found a [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342397/pythons-time-sleep-never-waking-up) here, but I don't actually get the point which he wanna say. Hope it will contribute to my problem.

**LATEST TEST**

Since using `chromedriver`, I added `driver.get("about:blank")` right before every return line in each function as below so as to force stopping async page-load of current page. and this force-stop-operation causes **ERROR ipc_channel_win.cc(370)] pipe error: 109** sometimes which does NOT affect the running of my program. Is this what affects my `time.sleep` function?

```
def retrieveCurHomePageAllSubjectUrls(driver):
    uri = "http://www.example.com/main.php?page=1"
    driver.get(uri)
    element = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('subject')
    subUrls = []
    for i in range(0, len(element)):
    subUrls.append(element[i].get_attribute('href').encode('utf-8'))
    driver.get("about:blank") #This is what I add
    return subUrls

def monitorFloorKeyword(subUrl):
    driver.get(subUrl)
    title = driver.find_element_by_id('subject_tpc').text
    content = driver.find_element_by_id('read_tpc').text
    if(title.find(u'keyword') >= 0 or content.find(u'keyword') >= 0):
    driver.get("about:blank") #This is what I add
    return (True,subUrl,title,content)
    driver.get("about:blank") #This is what I add
    return (False,)
```

**SEEM TO BE THE END**

As I said above, there's a **pipe error** right after I `driver.get("about:blank")` sometimes, nevertheless, the good news is that everything works normally this time. If anyone knows something about `selenium` which is relevant to this post, please inform me, I'd really apprieciate that.

Comment: You did wait for 5 minutes? Because `time.sleep(300)` means it's doing nothing for 5 minutes...

Comment: Since it's 5 min, Can you try it with a short sleep 5sec for example? this will tell if the problem is the sleep, also please fix your indention at the question.

Comment: yep, I just want it to do nothing for 5 minutes. But sometimes it just  doesn't wake up anymore. @rednaw

Comment: @Judking again, does it work for short sleeps 5sec, 10sec or so...?

Comment: As I said, it's unpredictable. Maybe 5-sec interval just works fine. FYI: although I set the time to 5 minutes, but in fact, the time is not accurate, 6 to 7 minutes of time span is common. I don't think it normal. @KobiK

Comment: It's probably wise to have the `fileHandle` close each time you're done with it, because now it stays open all the time, which prevents other processes from accessing it. It might also resolve your problem. See http://www.diveintopython.net/file_handling/file_objects.html for more info.

Comment: I've revised it and am testing again right now. But I did not manipulate the file in other processes or threads, is the close-right-after-writing will solve my problem?@rednaw

Comment: Yes, I've tried with no success. But I've found something which've been updated to my post. @rednaw

Comment: You're running this on Windows?

Comment: yes, win7 x86.64@Keith

Answer (score 0):

I took the time to simplify and clean up your code.

```
previously_seen_sub_urls = set()

with open('d:/seizeFloorRec.txt', 'a') as outfile:
    outfile.write(
        '\ncur time: ' +
        time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',time.localtime(time.time())) +
        '\n')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
while True:
    try:
        print "time: ", time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
                                      time.localtime(time.time()))
        sub_urls = aMethod(driver) # an irrelevant function which returns a list

        time.sleep(2)  # Why sleep here?

        print "max_cnt=[%d]" % len(sub_urls)
        for i, sub_url in enumerate(sub_urls):
            print "cur_idx=[%s]" % i
            try:
                rtn = monitorFloorKeyword(sub_urls[i])
                # rtn is either a length 1 tuple, first value False
                # or a length 4 tuple, (True, sub_url, title, content)

                time.sleep(1.5)

                if rtn[0]:
                    if rtn[1] not in previously_seen_sub_urls:
                        print "hit!"
                        previously_seen_sub_urls.add(rtn[1])
                        outfile.write(rtn[1]+'\t'+rtn[2].encode('utf-8')+'\n')
                        outfile.flush()
                    else:
                        print "hit but not write."

            except Exception as e:  # Should catch specific subclass of Exception
                print "exception when get page: ", sub_urls[i]
                print e
                # Continues

        print "sleep 5*60 sec..."
        time.sleep(300)  # PROBLEM POSSIBLY DOESN'T LIE HERE!!!
        print "sleep completes."

    except Exception as e:  #  Should catch specific subclass of Exception
        print 'exception!'
        print e
        time.sleep(20)
        # Continues
```

I haven't definitely found the problem, but I am suspicious of your exception handlers.

With your exception handlers, it is best to avoid "except Exception" apart from very limited situations (e.g. at the very outer loop of your code) because it shows you don't know what exception (or at least subclass of Exception) you are expecting to get, so it isn't clear whether the actions you take are correct.

The second problem is that you don't print the exception, but you print the exception's doc string. For Python's built-in exceptions, these strings may be useful, but they are not guaranteed to be set for custom exceptions. You may find exceptions are not displaying.

This doesn't explain your problem, but I would be interested to see if changing it to print the exception directly, rather than `e.__doc__` would help. (See also the `traceback` module to learn more about where an exception has come from.)

Comment: Thanks bro, but actually if you look through my post again, you'll find that there's **no exception** has been caught. It just stuck at `time.sleep` function as the output to cmd can prove it. What I've found now is that if I close the tab forcely, a **ERROR ipc_channel_win.cc(370)] pipe error: 109** will occur, so I thought there's some connections between this stuck thing and the `selenium`'s ipc with pipe operation.

Answer (score 0):

So get rid of `time.sleep` and try to use `implicitly_wait`

```
ff = webdriver.Firefox() 
ff.implicitly_wait(30)
```

or try to use `WebDriverWait`

```
ff = webdriver.Firefox()
ff.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
try:
    element = WebDriverWait(ff, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myDynamicElement")))
finally:
    ff.quit()
```

also check [about waits in selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html)